# Run DDL-script generated by Entity Framework does not create tables in Docker container

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, docker, ddl, boot2docker

So I decided that today would be the day for my first real hands-on with Docker. I wanted an Oracle  XE container for quickly starting and seeding a database when running integration and/or end-2-end tests. I have been using [this Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/kajnelissen/af6262f1934849f39261) for that purpose. The mentioned .sql-files have been generated as follows:

- **create_schema.sql**: Not generated, just sets up our ORP user and grants administrator privileges.
- **[create_ddl.sql](https://gist.github.com/kajnelissen/4d6d982712ec7d6d49ca)**: Generated by using the command `Update-Database -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -Script` in the Nuget package manager console.
- **create_dml.sql**: Seed data export from Toad For Oracle.

When running the scripts, `create_ddl.sql` does not create any tables, causing `create_dml.sql` to fail as it cannot find the tables it refers to. I am a bit stuck now. When I create a DDL-export with Toad For Oracle, the scripts run fine. However, I'd rather use the same DDL-script as the one used for development and deployment. I guess the failing has something to do with the migration history stuff that Entity Framework generates, but I don't really know why. If someone is be able to point me in the direction, that would be great.